# How can I make a symmetric histogram like this?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, while-loop

I'd like to write a JavaScript program that displays a symmetric histogram like this image:

[image]

The program should ask the user to enter the number of bars to print and the character to use to draw the bars. The count of characters in the bar needs to be displayed on the right-side of each bar.

The example showed is when I entered @ as the character and 13 as the number.

Here's my code:

```js
var symbol = prompt("Enter the symbol");
var number = prompt("Enter the number");
var currentNum = 1;
let text = "";
let symbolNum = symbol;

while (currentNum <= number) {
  text += "<br>" + symbolNum + " " + currentNum;
  symbolNum += symbol;
  currentNum++;
}


document.write(text + "<br>");
```

And at last, I only can output the following:

[image]

I'd like to know what I can do in order to reverse the loop?

Comment: In the task description it clearly says to use nested loops, why are you not doing that?

Comment: I am not sure how to do so

Comment: At least show that you made an attempt

Comment: I know what is nested loop, and I know how to do it. But I don't know how the nested loop can be implemented in this case :(

Comment: I agree. A nested loop is not the most efficient method to use here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different way for the same result. Not realy clean, but work.

```js
var symbol = prompt("Enter the symbol");
var number = prompt("Enter the number");
var currentNum = 1;
let textTOP = "";
let textBOTTOM = "";
let symbolNum = symbol;

while (currentNum <= number) {
  textTOP += "<br>" + symbolNum + " " + currentNum;
  if (currentNum < number)
      textBOTTOM = "<br>" + symbolNum + " " + currentNum + textBOTTOM;
  symbolNum += symbol;
  currentNum++;
}


document.write(textTOP + textBOTTOM + "<br>");
```

```js
var symbol = '@';
var number = 13;

var currentNum = 1;
let text = "";

while (currentNum < number * 2) {
  
  if (currentNum <= number) {
    
    let num = currentNum;
    text += "<br>" + symbol.repeat(num) + " " + num;
    
  } else {
    
    let num = Math.abs(number * 2 - currentNum);
    text += "<br>" + symbol.repeat(num) + " " + num;
    
  }
  
  currentNum++;
}


document.write(text + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function SymmetricHistogram(){
  
const size = 10;
let numberX = 0;
let numberY = 0;

for(let i = size; i>=-size; i--) {
  for(let j=size; j>=Math.abs(i); j--){
    process.stdout.write("@");
  }
  numberX <=size ? console.log(numberX++) : console.log(--numberY);
}

  }

  SymmetricHistogram();
```

Or try the below

https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3x58bqr3h

Comment: I got an error of {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 18,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: Paste this into your IDE and run the file. like test.js file and run "node test"

Comment: I am actually making a website with `<script src="index.js"></script>`

I ain't using `node.js`

Comment: @IanCHEUNG https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3x58bqr3h